# 'if' part not executing.. working on c#

Tags: c#

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select img.img from img inner join cars on img.carid= cars.carid where cars.carnum = '"+crn+"'", con);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Label2.Text = reader.GetString(0);
}

string car = Label2.Text;

if (car == null)
{
    string qry1 = "insert into img(img, carid)" + " values ('noimg.jpg', (select carid from cars where carnum ='" + crn + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(qry1, con);
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

int ab = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (ab != null)
{
    string myStringVariable = string.Empty;
    myStringVariable = "Your Car data has been entered";

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + myStringVariable + "');", true);
}
```

what I want to do is, if the select query of a image table passes null then inserts an default image in the database.. but if(car ==  null) portion is not executing at all. it skips the if part. WWhat to do?

Comment: Your car string is never null. You'll have to check if it's empty or `""`

Comment: its null.. I checked it through debugger

Comment: `string car = Label2.Text;` < This means it's never null, since you're assigning a value. Check if it's empty or `""`

Comment: Then `car` is not `null`.  An `if` block doesn't execute if the condition is false.

Comment: but Label2.Text doesnot contain any value

Comment: @Samsam , do you understand that an empty string `""` is _not_ the same as `null`?

Comment: Then it still assigns it a value. You'll have to read up the difference between null and an empty string (A.k.a. `""`)

Comment: On a side note, you might want to protect yourself from SQL injection. I really hope no one enters `; DROP TABLE img; --` as a value.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(car))`.  I doubt a label's text would ever be null rather than an empty string, i.e. `""`, but this would handle either case.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking for `NULL`; check for for both null and empty using `IsNullOrEmpty()` method or using `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` method like

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(car))
                {
```

(OR)

```
 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(car))
                {
```